# Why need the preposition "a" in "proprio sotto al mio naso", as opposed to "sotto un albero"?

Tags: prepositions

> proprio **sotto al** mio naso
>
> {vs}:  **sotto** un albero

I wonder why you need to use the two consecutive prepositions, "sotto" and "a", in the first example, even though its meaning does not seem any different from that in the second example.

When is the combination of "sotto" and "a" required?

Comment: I believe the preposition is optional in both cases.

Comment: I agree with egreg. Where did you find that you “need” to use that? And the whole phrase sounds slightly awkward: I'd say something like “[ce l'ho] proprio sotto il naso”, with no possessive adjective.

Comment: From [Treccani dictionary](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/sotto): «Con funzione prepositiva, sono frequenti le locuz. *sotto di*, usata spec. con i pron. personali tonici (*s. di me, s. di voi*), e *sotto a*, che, meno com. con la forma tonica dei pron. personali (*s. a te, s. a loro*), è invece frequente con sostantivi (*s. al letto*, *s. al pavimento*, che si alternano con *s. il letto*, *s. il pavimento*).»

Comment: Qualcuno potrebbe prendere la spiegazione del Treccani come spunto per scrivere una risposta?

Answer (score 3):

As explained in the [Treccani dictionary](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/sotto), the preposition *sotto* (actually an adverb that can be used as preposition) can be followed by

1. nothing,
2. *di*, or
3. *a*

before the main term. There is no difference in meaning. However, *di* is mostly used if the main term is a personal pronoun

> *sotto di me*, *sotto di loro*

and rarely used in other cases. The choice between nothing and *a* has no real rule when the use is not figurative. Thus

> *sotto il moggio
>
>   sotto al moggio*

and

> *me l'hanno fatta proprio sotto il naso
>
>   me l'hanno fatta proprio sotto al naso*

are essentially equivalent.<sup>1</sup> When the usage is figurative, nothing seems compulsory:

> *sotto l’alto patronato del presidente della Repubblica
>
>   combatterono sotto Cesare
>
>   patì sotto Ponzio Pilato*

In these cases, *sotto a* would not be used. The description in the dictionary

> **3**. Con funzione prepositiva, sono frequenti le locuzioni *sotto di*, usata specialmente con i pronomi personali tonici (*sotto di me*, *sotto di voi*), e *sotto a*, che, meno comunemente con la forma tonica dei pronomi personali (*sotto a te*, *sotto a loro*), è invece frequente con sostantivi (*sotto al letto*, *sotto al pavimento*, che si alternano con *sotto il letto*, *sotto il pavimento*).

is quite clear. If you look at the examples following the description, you actually never find *sotto a*.

Thus you are always right if you omit *a*, except in the case of a personal pronoun following *sotto*, where *di* should be preferred.

<sub><sup>1</sup> The possessive in *proprio sotto al mio naso* seems an Anglicism; in Italian the possessive is much less used than in English and in this case it is inappropriate.</sub>

Comment: When "proprio sotto al tuo naso" is meant as an equivalent of the figurative English expression "right under your nose", do you personally include the preposition "a"?